# How I sort list with enqueue function in c?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

My list :

```
list= C,3 -->C,5,---> A,7 --> A,5 --> G,2--> C,11 -->A,4
```

my outuput :

```
output= C,5  C,11 G,2 A,7 A,4 A,5 C,3
```

but there is some mistakes. I write my code like in answers and I write charcmp function and replace with strcmp with charcmp. It works sometime corrcectly. But usually first element is in the wrong place .My sorting code likes answer's code

Comment: There is no way that the `name` field can be a simple `char` and still support names like `"Kill"` and `"Bill"`. It must be either `char *` or `char name[32];` (or some other reasonable size). I realize this is a typo, but since it seems important to you to keep the given `struct`, it should probably be corrected.

Comment: Yeah you are right it is char *name i edited immediately :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code should do the work. It will add to the list in increasing age order:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _node_t {
    int age;
    char *name;
    struct _node_t *nextPtr;
} node_t;

node_t *node;

void enqueue(char *name, int age)
{
    node_t *p, *prev, *n;
    /* if empty list create first element and return */
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        node = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        node->nextPtr = NULL;
        node->name = (char *)malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
        strcpy(node->name, name);
        node->age = age;
        return;
    }
    p = prev = node;
    /* search last element or element with superior age value */
    while((p->nextPtr != NULL) && strcmp(p->name, name) < 0)
    {
        prev = p;
        p = p->nextPtr;
    }
    if (strcmp(p->name, name) == 0)
    {
        while((p->nextPtr != NULL) && p->age < age)
        {
            prev = p;
            p = p->nextPtr;
        }
    }
    /* create the new element and store the data */
    n = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    n->name = (char *)malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    strcpy(n->name, name);
    n->age = age;
    /* insert the new element */
    if ((strcmp(p->name, name) < 0) || (strcmp(p->name, name) == 0 && p->age < age))
    {
        n->nextPtr = p->nextPtr;
        p->nextPtr = n;
    }
    else
    {
        n->nextPtr = p;
        if (prev->nextPtr == p)
        {
            prev->nextPtr = n;
        }
        else if (node == p)
        {
            node = n;
        }
    }
}

void printNodes()
{
    node_t *p;
    p = node;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s, %d\n", p->name, p->age);
        p = p->nextPtr;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    node = NULL;
    enqueue("Kill", 15);
    enqueue("Bill", 2);
    enqueue("Kill", 7);
    printNodes();

    return 0;
}
```

So the following adding:

```
enqueue("Kill", 15);
enqueue("Bill", 2);
enqueue("Kill", 7);
```

Will store it in the order printed by `printNodes()`:

```
Bill, 2
Kill, 7
Kill, 15
```

UPDATED:

Added name sorting then age.

Comment: OP want not only age order.

Comment: but i can't sort for name :/

Comment: Please give me some advice for sorting names. Can i use strcmp ?? @BLUEPIXY and daouzli

Comment: @user yes you use strcmp

Comment: May I know why I have -1? I said it sorts by age. The OP is not clear and speaks about two structs for sorting while there is only one struct! If it's not exactly what expected, it does at least a part of the work and can be updated!

Comment: Anyway I updated the code to sort first the name and then the age. It was an obvious and really minimal chage to the code. @user3668199 I hope this is the expected answer

Comment: @user3668199 You're welcome. Don't hesitate to add a point and accept the answer (see http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)

Comment: @daouzli So, do you have any idea for compare just one single character ? I want to compare C,G and A.  C is the most priority character and then G and then A. I didn't do that

Comment: @daouzli and do you have any idea of my question ??

Comment: @user3668199 I followed your link and it seems you got your answer. If you wanted to do it with my code you have to replace the strcmp checking by something adapted

Comment: I write compare function and return -1, 1 or 0 . but in your code works with strcmp.  I replaced strcmp with compare but my output doesn't work good

Comment: try a basic program to test your function and be sure it returns expected result

Comment: @daouzli I write a basic code it works usually. But there is an mistake sometimes. I don't know why . I add my code and my output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
/*Queue has five properties. capacity stands for the maximum number of elements Queue can hold.
  Size stands for the current size of the Queue and elements is the array of elements. front is the
 index of first element (the index at which we remove the element) and rear is the index of last element
 (the index at which we insert the element) */
typedef struct Queue
{
        int capacity;
        int size;
        int front;
        int rear;
        int *elements;
}Queue;
/* crateQueue function takes argument the maximum number of elements the Queue can hold, creates
   a Queue according to it and returns a pointer to the Queue. */
Queue * createQueue(int maxElements)
{
        /* Create a Queue */
        Queue *Q;
        Q = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
        /* Initialise its properties */
        Q->elements = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*maxElements);
        Q->size = 0;
        Q->capacity = maxElements;
        Q->front = 0;
        Q->rear = -1;
        /* Return the pointer */
        return Q;
}
void Dequeue(Queue *Q)
{
        /* If Queue size is zero then it is empty. So we cannot pop */
        if(Q->size==0)
        {
                printf("Queue is Empty\n");
                return;
        }
        /* Removing an element is equivalent to incrementing index of front by one */
        else
        {
                Q->size--;
                Q->front++;
                /* As we fill elements in circular fashion */
                if(Q->front==Q->capacity)
                {
                        Q->front=0;
                }
        }
        return;
}
int front(Queue *Q)
{
        if(Q->size==0)
        {
                printf("Queue is Empty\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        /* Return the element which is at the front*/
        return Q->elements[Q->front];
}
void Enqueue(Queue *Q,int element)
{
        /* If the Queue is full, we cannot push an element into it as there is no space for it.*/
        if(Q->size == Q->capacity)
        {
                printf("Queue is Full\n");
        }
        else
        {
                Q->size++;
                Q->rear = Q->rear + 1;
                /* As we fill the queue in circular fashion */
                if(Q->rear == Q->capacity)
                {
                        Q->rear = 0;
                }
                /* Insert the element in its rear side */ 
                Q->elements[Q->rear] = element;
        }
        return;
}
int main()
{
        Queue *Q = createQueue(5);
        Enqueue(Q,1);
        Enqueue(Q,2);
        Enqueue(Q,3);
        Enqueue(Q,4);
        printf("Front element is %d\n",front(Q));
        Enqueue(Q,5);
        Dequeue(Q);
        Enqueue(Q,6);
        printf("Front element is %d\n",front(Q));
}
```

Comment: But in my code , there is structure which name is node and it seems :

Comment: struct node{ int age;  char name; struct node *nextPtr; }

Comment: Thank you but I must do something different like your code :/ i don't know

Comment: @DDave Your code does not match the OP's question. He is trying to write a priority queue, not a queue.

Answer (score -1):

A solution using double pointers is probably the best. You are implementing a priority queue technically, not a list. You implement it by keeping a linked list that is sorted. The dequeue operation on a priority queue will remove the first item from the list.

As this is a homework assignment I set it up for you but you need to complete the rest so you can actually learn the important stuff.

EXIT CONDITION HERE -> This is where you want to check when you have found the item where you will insert after. Write this condition so that the loop exits when this occurs.

EDIT ^^ -> When I say the item where you will insert after what I mean is that the item you currently are looking at is the first item that is "greater" than temp. `queue` will be pointing to the next pointer to that item. I also added a line in the code that will make set `temp`'s next to point to that item. When you update `*queue` you are saying that you want to make the next pointer on the previous item point to `*temp`.

update the pointer here -> This is where you update `queue` to point to the next pointer of the next person in the list/queue.

```
typedef struct Person {
   char name[20];
   int age;
   struct Person *next;
} Person;

void enqueue(Person **queue, char *name, int age) {
   Person *temp = calloc(1, sizeof(Person));
   strncpy(temp->name, name, 20);
   temp->age = age;

   while (*queue && "EXIT CONDITION HERE")
      //update the pointer here;

   temp->next = *queue; //forgot this line originally. You need it!!
   *queue = temp; //.this sets the next pointer of last item or head to temp
}


...

Person *queue = NULL;
enqueue(&queue, "Bob", 10);
enqueue(&queue, "John", 5);

Then print the list to check that enqueue works correctly.
```

Comment: Thanks it is helpful but I'm not understand one thing. My teacher said to your enqueue function 's header must be like this :             void enqueue(char name, int age);

Comment: Is the list kept in a global variable? If so, use that instead. You can simply write `Person **queue = &GLOBAL_VARIABLE;` and use what I have.

Comment: @user3668199 Also, if you have char *name in the struct, you need to malloc space for it also and copy the name parameter in. You could set it to equal the parameter if you are guaranteed to be passed a string constant (such as enqueue("Bob", 10)). In other cases the name parameter may be freed or if it is a static string (on the stack) go out of scope, so you need to make a copy.

Comment: @user3668199 I made an edit to what I originally had. You should read what I wrote before you start doing this because what I gave you originally will lead to some problems. I apologize for that.