# How to priority sort characters?

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures

I edit my question. I wrote my functions. But there is some mistakes in output .How can I fix it ?

```
void enqueue(char type,int p){
 if (que == NULL){
    que =malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    que->nextPtr = NULL;
    que->pages=p;
    que->userType=type;
    return;
}
q = prev = que;

while((q->nextPtr != NULL) && charcmp(q->userType,type)<0){
    prev = q;
    q = q->nextPtr;
}
if(charcmp(q->userType,type)==0){
    while(q->nextPtr !=NULL && q->pages < p){
         prev = q;
         q = q->nextPtr;    
    } 
}

n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
n->pages=p;
n->userType=type;

if ( (charcmp(q->userType,type) < 0 || charcmp(q->userType,type)==0 ) && q->pages < p){
    n->nextPtr = q->nextPtr;
    q->nextPtr = n;
}
if((q->pages >= p )){
    n->nextPtr = q;
    if (prev->nextPtr == q){
        prev->nextPtr = n;
    }
    else if (que == q)
    {
        que = n;
    }
}
```

}

and this is my charcmp function .

```
int charcmp(char a,char b){
while(a==b){
    return 0;
}

while(a!=b){

if(a=='C' && (b=='G'|| b=='A')){
    return -1;
}

if(a=='G' && (b=='A')){
    return -1;
}

if(a=='A' && (b=='C' || b=='G')){
    return 1;
}
if(a=='G' && b=='C'){
    return 1;
}
}
 }
```

My output has some mistakes. I can't fix it.For example its return C,C,A,C,G

Comment: What code do you have so far? What's the program input, where's that relation `C > G > A` coming from?

Comment: Ok i'm editing my question with answers for your question

Comment: What I mean, is that in the current form, "sort three characters, given that `C precedes G precedes A`" you can write a function that returns `C, G, A` regardless of the input.

Comment: Actually, I must sort for 2 different things. One of them numbers and the other char . I sort numbers with enqueue function but I can't do that char :/

Comment: I suggest that you try to write a function signature, sample inputs and sample outputs to specify what you want.

Comment: @bereal OK, i wrote in my code now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to sort an array of custom objects, like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char c;  // a character
    int i;   // a number
} pair;
```

Then you can apply a standard function [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) with a custom compare function like this:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    pair *p1 = (pair*) a;
    pair *p2 = (pair*) b;
    if (p1->c == p2->c) return p1->i - p2->i;
    if (p1->c == 'C' || p1->c == 'G' && p2->c == 'A') return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

So that this testing code with your test data will print `C,1 C,8 G,2 G,5 A,4 A,7 A,10`

```
int main() {
    pair input[] = {{'A', 10}, {'A', 7}, {'G', 5},
                    {'C', 8}, {'A', 4}, {'C', 1}, {'G', 2}};
    qsort(input, 7, sizeof(pair), compare);
    pair *cur = input;
    for (int i=0; i<7; ++i, ++cur) {
        printf("%c,%d ", cur->c, cur->i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

How to transform arbitrary input into array of structures, is an exercise.

Comment: I want to ask a question to you. function int compare just return -1 and 1. Can I change it return ? For example can I write 0 and 1 ?

Comment: @user3668199 Function `compare` must comply with the `qsort`'s contract: _returns ​a negative integer value if the first argument is less than the second, a positive integer value if the first argument is greater than the second and zero if the arguments are equal._

Comment: but in your code it returns -1 when p1=c or p1=g and p2=a .I'm confused does it return 1 ??

Comment: If `p1=c`, then `p1` precedes ("less than") `p2` regardless of the numeric value. Same when `p1=g` and `p2=a`  (we already know, that the chars are different). In both cases return `-1`, so that `p1` goes before `p2`. Note that `qsort` puts smaller values first, so we return `-1` for "has higher priority" rather than for "less than".

Comment: I write code like your example. But I must sort by using enqueue and this step can I use qsort method ??

Comment: What is enqueue in this case?

Comment: function enqueue : void enqueue(char a,int b);      a is character C,G,A  and b is number

Comment: So, what is it expected to do?

Comment: can you look at my other question topic. I can explain that this enqueue .   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824948/how-i-sort-list-with-enqueue-function-in-c/23830120?noredirect=1#comment36738932_23830120

Comment: As already said there in the comments, just replace `strcmp` check with your own function like `charcmp(char a, char b)`, which is like 5 lines long and 10 times simpler than the original task.

Comment: I edited my question please help me. I write mos of my codes and it has still mistakes.

Comment: Question you ask in StackOverflow should be of potential use for other visitors. In the current form it makes no sense whatsoever. Consider rolling back and asking a new question, preferably containing [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char inputChar[] = {'A', 'C', 'G'};
    char bufferChar[3] = {'\0', '\0', '\0'};

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(inputChar[i] == 'C')
            bufferChar[0] = inputChar[i];
        else if(inputChar[i] == 'G')
            bufferChar[1] = inputChar[i];
        else
            bufferChar[2] = inputChar[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", bufferChar[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. Try fiddle with the **inputChar** you would still get C G A

Comment: Do I understand correct that the program will return `C, G, A` regardless of the `inputChar`? If so, how is this program different from `int main() { printf("CGA\n"); }`

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can't explain very well but I must use enqueue function with create and sort

Comment: What the... ?!You are actually right! If the input is uniquely randomized between the three char A, C, G and sort them. Just print C, G, A . *Facepalm*

Comment: The input is not only characters it also has numbers. But i can sort numbers, i ddin't write it question

Comment: Why don't you try to show the output of what you want. Instead of explaining it in words.